# Safari Notification.permission state can't be reset

Tags: push-notification, safari, permissions, web-push

I'm testing safari 16+ versions' push api capabilities using a service worker. After i clicked allow on the push notification dialog, Notification.permission goes granted. Then for testing purposes i reset the notification permissions from settings->websites->notifications and remove the website i opted-in.
Now this notifications list is empty but when i go to that site and check Notification.permission it still prompts "granted".

I was expecting to find a way to reset the permission state so that i can follow same steps from scratch. But i'm not able to make permission state to "default" once it is set. At first i was able to see the website in notifications list but after some time and couple of trials it shows nothing.

I tried to flush all the safari's cache, updating the version and restart the browser. But i couldn't find a way to reset this setting to be able to do tests from scratch. The list under settings->websites->notifications is still empty.

Tried safari Version 16.0 16.1 and 16.2 they all acted the same.

Comment: Please consider filing a bug report at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i've just found a workaround solution for this issue.

Your Notification Permissions are storing
`~/Library/Safari/RemoteNotifications/Permissions.plist` file.
You can not change it on your terminal but you can follow this steps:

- Be sure Safari already closed.
- Firstly copy this XML and create a file with same name (`Permissions.plist`) on somewhere.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict/>
</plist>
```

- Go to Safari Folder via: $ `cd ~/Library/Safari`
- Open this folder on Finder: $ `open .`
- Scroll down and find `RemoteNotifications` folder and open it
- Change `Permissions.plist` file's name as `old_Permissions.plist` (maybe you need it later)
- Drag your new clean `Permissions.plist` file here
- Congrats. You can open Safari now and old Notification permissions will be reseted.